# CSS Techniques Border with a horizontal line to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a border that connects a horizontal line from the right. The sketch below is how it should look like, and I need ideas on how to create this. Thank you! I would greatly appreciate it on anyone who can help me.

[image]

Comment: what is your idea? Show what you tried and what is your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example.

```css
#example {
  position: relative;
}
#example:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}
#example span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #999;
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <span>LATEST PRODUCTS</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F0F;
    position: relative;
}
.test:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    content: "";
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: A little explanation, or a partial demo on how the code works would be a great improvement to this question. consider adding one.